# Smarty Template inheritance in both directions

Tags: inheritance, smarty, parent

I have the following problem. If i understood smarty correctly, this Code should be work.

File parent:

```
//some stuff

{block name="childDoYourThing"}
   {block name="value1"}value1{/block}
{/block}

//some other stuff
```

File child:

```
{extends file="./parent.tpl"}

{block name="childDoYourThing"}
   //severalcode
   {block name="value1"}{$smarty.block.parent}{/block}
{/block}
```

The Code in `childDoYourThing` is executed correctly, but in the block `value1` I get the error: "No content applied"

Could you tell if this can be solved and how?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The result of launching this code is:

> //some stuff //severalcode value1 //some other stuff

so everything is working as expected.

If you have this error you should make sure you use the latest Smarty version